# Postgresql in Python - Joining tables on a matching variable that is not showing as matching

Tags: python, postgresql

I have two tables in a database, 1 is a table of NFL teams (teams) and the other is a table of NFL games (games). The games table has the full team name of the home team (team_home) and the away team (team_away), the teams table has the full team name (team_name) and the team id (team_id) such as SF for San Fransisco 49ers.

I need to update the games table so that the code is what shows up in the team_home and team_away columns instead of the full team names. However, even though I can see matches in the columns, it keeps returning an error (`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`) the code below should work for this:

```
for x, row in games.iterrows():
    
    # look up team_id from teams based on team_home in games
    cursor.execute("""SELECT team_id FROM teams WHERE team_name = %s""",
                  (games.loc[x]['team_home'],))
    team_home_id = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    
    # Look up team_id from teams based on team_away in games
    cursor.execute("""SELECT team_id FROM teams WHERE team_name = %s""",
                  (games.loc[x]['team_away'],))
    team_away_id = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

I have implemented a code to call out what teams aren't finding matches:

```
for x, row in games.iterrows():

    try:
        # look up team_id from teams based on team_home in games
        cursor.execute("""SELECT team_id FROM teams WHERE team_name = %s""",
                      (games.loc[x]['team_home'],))
        team_home_id = cursor.fetchone()[0]
        print(team_home_id)

    except TypeError:
        print(f"No match found for home team name: {games.loc[x]['team_home']}")
        team_home_id = None

    try:
        # Look up team_id from teams based on team_away in games
        cursor.execute("""SELECT team_id FROM teams WHERE team_name = %s""",
                      (games.loc[x]['team_away'],))
        team_away_id = cursor.fetchone()[0]
        print(team_away_id)

    except TypeError:
        print(f"No match found for away team name: {games.loc[x]['team_away']}")
        team_away_id = None
```

This returns information that there are a few that aren't finding matches, but when I look them up they have matches on both sides. I've tried removing leading and trailing whitespace on both sides to see if that was an issue but still got the same result.

Some of the main issues as far as team names are Oakland Raiders, San Diego Chargers, St. Louis Cardinals, Washington Redskins, and New England Patriots.

The data is very large, so I have moved it into a google sheet for reference.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y3PA-WhaOgq2H3jpuovZQgTLwGF8-t9JSU_shYY56eg/edit#gid=1701285808

This sheet has what data is in the games table and in the teams table on separate tabs. I have also added a "check matches" tab to this where I copied the list of teams from each of the tables, then made a list with only the unique values, sorted them alphabetically and then did a quick logical formula to check if all unique values have a match and they do.

Comment: Remember that it must be an EXACT match.  No abbreviations, no extra punctuation, no extra spaces.  Also, remember that you can have SQL do this lookup for you by using a join -- you can get the "games" rows with the ID already looked up, all in one query.

Comment: Is it the same names that don't match every time?  Which one(s)?

Comment: Mostly it is always the ones I mentioned just above the google data link